# Impedance matching for custom level translator board

Tags: level-translation

I have designed a custom board using [SN74LVC1T45](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjtkaKZpvjlAhXKXSsKHfPfAMMQFjAAegQIBhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn74lvc1t45&usg=AOvVaw3pbgT92HKiEzszLt0xrm54). I have followed the schematic of EVM and added few 150R resistors at input and output for reducing the ringing effect.
The custom board will be receiving inputs from an FPGA board and level translating.

The board operating frequency is 10Hz to 20Mhz. I have verified the custom board with signal generator without impedance mathching resistors and results are satisfactory.

Should I use impedance matching resistors at output and input?

EVM Schematic:-
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Impedance matching is needed when terminating a [transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line). Almost any (wire, pcb) connection can be considered a transmission line when the **length** of the connection (wire, pcb trace) is longer than the **wavelength** of the signal.

Your signal is a logic signal of up to 20 MHz. Since that signal will have steep slopes (it is not a sine wave) it will contain higher order harmonics. Let's assume these harmonics are relevant up to 200 MHz, then we have to consider that our signal has a 200 MHz bandwidth. 200 MHz means a wavelength of:

\$\lambda = c/f = 3*10^8\ /\ 200*10^6 =\$ 1.5 m

**Is your signal travelling over a connection in the order of 1.5 meter or more?**

If **yes** then you need to use a cable with a certain characteristic impedance and terminate that cable at both sides with that impedance. Then the effect of signal reflections will be minimized and your signal should travel without being harmed much.

If **no**, your connection is much smaller than 1.5 meter, then you don't need to use a transmission line connection. You don't need to consider any characteristic impedance and you don't need to terminate the connections. Since the distance is quite short the effect of signal reflections should be negligible.

Note the relation between bandwidth of the signal and distance. For very high frequencies like the connection between a CPU and RAM running at a few GHz, even the small distance on a PCB needs a proper transmission line. The old analog phone system uses very low frequencies (a few kHz) but the connection still needs to be terminated properly as the distance can be very high (many km).

Comment: the input connection to the custom board falls below the 1.5m range. But the output may or may not be less than 1.5m. In this case what is the appropriate thing to do ?

Comment: What I would do is: for the input assume no termination is needed. For the output I would at least make a provision (have places for the components on the PCB but leave these places empty for the moment) to have proper termination etc. so that I can add it later if needed. Then I could try if things are OK without the termination and if not then add the termination.

Comment: SN74LVC1T45 is a bidirectional Level translator, so I need to provide provision at both input and output. I may use it for level translation from A to B or B to A.